# HTTP/HTTPS basic authentication: colon in username

Tags: http, https

This may be a basic question, but is it possible to have colon (":") in username when there is HTTP or HTTPS basic authentication ? If not, is there a way we can escape colon ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at RFC - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2 and around the web, there doesn't seem to be escaping technique for colon in username. The only place extra you can have it is in password field.

If it is an option, you maybe can replace : with @ in auth level and ask users to do this.

Answer (score 37):

the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2  states clearly that the username must not include a colon:

> To receive authorization, the client sends the userid and password, separated by a single colon (":") character, within a base64 [7] encoded string in the credentials.`
>
> basic-credentials = base64-user-pass
>
> `base64-user-pass  = <base64 [4] encoding of user-pass, except not limited to 76 char/line>`
>
> `user-pass   = userid ":" password`
>
> `userid      = * <TEXT excluding ":">`
>
> `password    = *TEXT`

Based on this, there is no way to use a colon within the username.

Comment: In the meanwhile obsoleted by [RFC7617](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617) which states even more clearly: _User-ids containing colons cannot be encoded in user-pass strings._