# basic httpurlconnection POST request failing with 401

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

I have tried multiple things to correct this and not sure what the issue is. For the POST request I have tried encoding the username credentials in Base64 and and set as requestProperty values. Also tried adding it as parameters to the POST body but in both instances the request fails with a 401 error. Clearly the credentials are not being recognized although when used in POSTMAN request it works fine. I then duplicated the headers used in that request with the BASIC auth value and still the same error code. Perhaps I am not seeing the issue clearly:

```
    obj = new URL(urlRequest);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.28.3");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
    //String userCredentials = "_username=xxxxxxxx&_password=yyyyyyyy";
    //String basicAuth = "Basic " + new 
      String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
    //conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    conn.setRequestProperty("_username", "xxxxxxxxxx");
    conn.setRequestProperty("_password", "yyyyyyyyyy");
    
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_username", "xxxxxxxxxx"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_password", "yyyyyyyyyy"));
    String urlParameters = "_username=xxxxxxxxxx&_password=yyyyyyyyyy";
    
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
    }

    InputStream urlInputStream; 
    int errCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader inSt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), 
      "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
```

Comment: please share the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

#### HTTP Basic Authentication

In the HTTP Basic authentication scheme Base64 encoded credentials are in form of `username:password`. Try this:

```java
String username = "xxxxxxxxxx", password = "yyyyyyyyyy";
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +
  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
    (username + ":" + password).getBytes()));
```

[RFC2617: HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2617#section-2)

> To receive authorization, the client sends the userid and password, separated by a single colon (":") character, within a base64 encoded string in the credentials.

(As a side note: You [can't have colon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612931/2158271) in the username.)

#### Content-Type

If content is not in [multipart format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23517227/2158271) the `Content-Type` header should be changed accordingly. In case of content format `key1=value1&key2=value2&...` try this:

```java
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/2158271) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the response; yes I tried this and unfortunately the same 401. This is so frustrating. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer. Check the value of Content-Type header.